# Max of four <td>'s, then start new <tr> (MySQL Query)

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
$i = '';
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlqry)){
    echo '<td><a href="'. $res['link'] .'"><img src="'. $res['link'] .'" style="border: 0px; width: 150px; height: 150px;" alt="afbeelding"></a></td>';
    $i++;
    if($i = '4'){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

I want to set a max of 4 `<td>`s, then set a new `<tr>` when I get something from a mysql table, only this is not w3 valid and not working.

How can I make this work, and set other `<td>`s when there are less then 8 results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
if($i = '4'){
```

That's assigning `'4'` to `$i`. You probably want to do something like:

```
if($i % 4 == 0){
```

In other words, every time `$i` divided by four is an even division (there's no remainder), start a new `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<table>';
for ($i=0, $max = 4; $res = mysql_fetch_(...); ) {
    if ($i++ % $max == 0)
        echo '<tr>';

    echo '<row stuff>';

    if ($i % $max == 0)
        echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

You can also hardcode `$max` if you prefer. This also generates no "phantom" rows.

Tip: Don't use a `'string'` if your value is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i have been doing it for years....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>4 Column Display Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
//connection

$con = mysqli_connect("Host", "UserName", "Password", "TableName");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Database connection is - <strong>unsuccessful</strong> ' . mysqli_error());
  }
//The Query
 $get_query_sql = "SELECT * FROM Query";
 $get_query_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_query_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

//The Results
while  ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_query_res)) {

$Column1 = $res['Column1'];
$Column2 = $res['Column2'];

//Table display
echo '<table align="center" border="1px" bordercolor="#999999" cellpadding="5px"     cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="vertical-align:middle">';
echo '<tr>';
 $i = 1;

echo '<td align="middle" height="200px" width="200px"><strong>ID =</strong> '.$Column1.' and the <strong>Number =</strong>'.$Column2.' </td>'; 
if($i++ % 4 == 0){
    echo '</tr><tr>';
   }
}
 echo '</tr>';
 echo '</table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($i == 4){
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    $i = 0;
}
```

Should work fine, I've done similar code before, you'll need to also fill out the last row with blanks (or use a colspan).

Edit:

Or get fancy:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
$i = 0;
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlqry)){
    echo '<td><a href="'. $res['link'] .'"><img src="'. $res['link'] .'" style="border: 0px; width: 150px; height: 150px;" alt="afbeelding"></a></td>';
    if($i++ % 4 == 0){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```